# Weird Characters in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

I sometimes see weird characters on some websites instead of what they're meant to display. I've attached an image below as an example. In IE the site displays correctly but on Chrome there are weird characters instead.

My encoding settings on Chrome are set to Auto detect/Unicode UTF-8. I've tried reinstalling all my Windows default fonts too but no success.

Does anyone have a fix for this? Most solutions I've looked at haven't been successful

[image]

Comment: Since you mentioned it: What solutions have you tried?

Comment: Reinstalling fonts (which was a solution I found here, trying different encoding settings, reinstalling Chrome,

The encoding one seems to be the most common solution I've come across

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the solution. I had a couple of corrupted/bad Helvetica fonts so I got rid of all of those and found some fresh new ones. Problem solved.

Comment: I simply changed my font on Chrome from Arial to Times New Roman and it works

Answer (score 2):

Probably an encoding problem.  It's not unique to Chrome, either: I see it all the time in Firefox.  Try a different encoding (In chrome, click the wrench>Tools>Encoding).  Western will probably fix it.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to have fixed it. Strangely enough when I un-did the change, it was still fixed. Maybe it had something to do with a recent Chrome update. Anyways problem solved :)

Comment: Different encodings mess up with unusual Unicode characters; that fix is broken form start.

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution did not work (my case) I have a solution that should work for everyone.

To fix this simply install "Font Changer with Google Web Fonts" and you should be good to go! Only down side is that know every font is the same, but it's still better than seeing "HV%/(Viun&#okIUYGy8765&%$" and guessing that it means "Next".

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by following these easy steps:

1. Go to *Settings*.
2. Click *Show advanced settings*.
3. Under *Web content* next to *Font size* click *Customize font* and choose *Times New Roman*.