# Google Chrome (Windows) not displaying text/encoding correctly on certain websites

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I experience a problem similar to [Weird Characters in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/408020/weird-characters-in-google-chrome)

Here's a screenshot on the website http://getfwd.com 
[image: weird characters]

I've tried:

- Removing fonts I have installed
- Setting the encoding to Western, UTF-8, Greek, Automatic
- Changing the fonts used in Google Chrome
- Removing Google Chrome, including all application data/user profiles
- Running CCleaner
- Reinstalling Google Chrome, twice
- Installing Chromium (fonts display fine in Chromium)
- Turning off Windows ClearType
- Changing Windows/Chrome languages from English (Australia) to US, UK
- Restarting Windows several times after making changes

All of which did not work. I do not connect over VPN/proxy.

Can anyone give me any tips?

Windows 7 x64 Ultimate

Comment: So you removed the fonts, did you then install them again correctly ?
In Google Chrome Settings have you set the Encoding to UTF-8? My Settings look like this: Standard Font→ Times New Roman, Serif Font→ Times New Roman, Sans-Serif Font→ Arial, Fixed-width font→ Courier New, Encoding→ Utf-8 Unicode

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this would help:

[Improve font rendering in Google Chrome 35 or newer on Windows](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/04/15/improve-font-rendering-google-chrome-35-newer-windows/) (April 15, 2014)

> [...]
>
> The main issue here is that Chrome uses Windows GDI to render fonts while most modern web browsers that run on Windows use DirectWrite instead.
>
> The Chrome development team has integrated full support for DirectWrite into Chrome Beta -- and Dev and Canary as well -- but have not enabled it by default.A
>
> [...]
>
> 1. Type or paste chrome://flags into the browser's addressbar and hit enter.
> 2. Hit F3 and type directwrite. Chrome should jump to the Enable DirectWrite experiment right away.
> 3. Click on the enable link to activate it.
> 4. A relaunch now button appears that you need to click on to restart the browser.
>
> [...]

It worked for me. Apparently, the problem is with the rendering of web fonts.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be an issue with Helvetica and Helvetica Neue. Twitch.tv provided a solution that worked for mere here: http://support.twitch.tv/discussion/4148/garbled-text-in-chrome-read-this

Comment: Please add a bit of summary, the link _will_ break sometime...

Comment: It actually appears to have broken already.