# Google Chrome showing weird character

Tags: windows, google-chrome

[image: weird character is showing in Google Chrome]

Whenever I am trying to open some sites and also sending messages in LinkedIn it showing something weird.

Comment: Related [post](http://superuser.com/questions/408020/weird-characters-in-google-chrome)

Comment: My problem did't solved after changing fonts and encoding.

Comment: That web works well for me in Chrome. The broken content is being loaded by javascript dynamically, so it is not a part of page source html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those weird characters is actually the file content that is not rendered correctly in your browser. Along with each response received from a website for each resource (html, images, stylesheets, javascript, etc) there is a 'Content-type' header, which tells the browser what resource type is it. In your case it might be a browser extension that is altering the headers, a bug in the browser, an antivirus or something else. Try to use a different browser or update the current one.

Comment: I don't know which extension is causing problem, but in other browsers every link is working fine, also my browser is up to date with Version 51.0.2704.106 m (64-bit). And don't have any antivirus.

Comment: Thanx! machineaddict actually it was one of the extension that causing problem. I disabled all because I don't know which extension was creatiing problem now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

- Try using another browser.
- Re-install Google Chrome.
- *Reset* Google Chrome.

If these don't work, contact Google support. Also perform an anti-virus check if you haven't.